# problem with deploying in anchor

Tags: anchor, deploy

please help me to solve the problem, I am new to solana.
on startup `anchor build`   i get:

```
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

i am using WSL, thanks in advance.